# How to refresh an imageview in Swift without reloading the page?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a update photo button that connects to facebookgraphAPI and downloads the current user's profile picture.
I want the image on my view to refresh, without reloading the `viewController`.
Is there some way to do this? I know `tableview` has `reloadData` and `refreshcontrol` but I'm not using a `tableview`.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController , UITextViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profileTextView: UITextView!


@IBAction func updatePicture(sender: UIButton) {
    // pulls in latest facebook profile info
    let vc = ViewController()
    vc.getFBUserInfo(PFUser.currentUser()!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.loadPhoto()
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadProfile()
    loadPhoto()
}

func loadPhoto() {
    currentUser()?.getPhoto({
        image in
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.imageView.contentMode = .Center
        self.imageView.image = image
    })
}

func loadProfile () {
    nameLabel.text = currentUser()?.name

    // get the existing profile from DB
    if let profile = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("profileText") as? String {
        profileTextView.text = profile
    }

    profileTextView.delegate = self
}
```

User.swift getPhoto function:

```
func getPhoto(callback:(UIImage) -> ()) {
    let imageFile = pfUser.objectForKey("picture") as! PFFile
    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        data, error in
        if let data = data {
            callback(UIImage(data: data)!)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: try to set `self.imageView.image = nil` first before changing it to a new image

Answer (score 4):

Your callback looks like it might be being called on a background queue. UIKit doesn't like it when you access its classes in the background and a common side effect is that it looks like the UI doesn't update (or doesn't update until after a delay).

Try

```
func loadPhoto() {
    currentUser()?.getPhoto({
        image in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
               self.imageView.contentMode = .Center
               self.imageView.image = image
            })

    })
}
```